# How to Parse External content URL in DB connected via BCS Model in On Premises Search?

Tags: search, enterprise-search, bcs, hybrid-taxonomy

I have crawled through External content located in DB in which one Column is having links that are all documents either word or ppt or pdf.

I am able to display the row data's in Search, Would like to parse/ read through that URL content and display the results with Author details etc.

Is it possible in Sp 2016 / O365 ?If yes/no can you please provide guidance on the same?

Answer (score 1):

Your external content type has to return the document to the crawler. Alternatively you could just crawl the location where the files are stored.

Comment: I can crawl the content , that will return the document, but i would like to retain other information that are mapped to the documents . Hence looking forward for any other alternative.  Is there any way we could achieve this?

Comment: If you are indexing the doc, the Author managed property should be available.